# CloudKit : CKQuery showing error: error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (CKErrorDomain error 1.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit, ckquery

I working on iOS app implementing cloudkit but I need to query all the records with ID greater then a number. For example I have record with ID of  23:

[image]

here is my code:

```
CKContainer *myContainer = [CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:containerID];

    CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [myContainer publicCloudDatabase];


CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"23"];
    CKReference* recordToMatch = [[CKReference alloc] initWithRecordID:recordID action:CKReferenceActionNone];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordID >= %@", recordToMatch];
    CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:recordType predicate:predicate];

    [publicDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {

            NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        else {

        }
    }];
```

But I'm getting the following error:

error:  error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (CKErrorDomain error 1.)

Any of you knows how can I setup my NSPredicate in a way where I can get all the records with ID greater then 23 ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you want to compare with a record ID?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Because I need all the records with ID greater then 23 or any giving number

Comment: Okay, why do you need records with an ID greater than a given number? An ID is an Id, no property.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad that is exactly what I tried to do but did work. "recordID.recordName"

Comment: I did not say, that you should do something. So you cannot do, what I intended to do. You went to SO to get a solution for your problem. It would make things easier, if you respond to the questions. Again: Why do you need records with an ID greater than a given number?

Comment: Because I have records with ID greater than a given number. In this case I'm looking for records with ID of 24,25,26 ... n .

Answer (score 1):

For a query like this you could use a predicate like:

in Swift:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordID >= %@", CKRecordID(recordName: "23"))
```

In Objective C:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordID >= %@", [CKRecordID initWithRecordName:@"23"]];
```

Then I do assume that you created the CKRecords object originally while specifying this number. Otherwise recordID values will be assigned by CloudKit and will be a GUID.

Comment: I tried you solution but I get this error: Field '___recordID' has a value type of REFERENCE and cannot be queried using filter type GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS

Comment: Then the only way to achieve this is by adding an extra text field with the same value and then just query that text field.

Comment: Can you explain with a example?

Comment: When creating a record also creat and fill a field like for instance myID, Then the predicate will just be:  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myID >= %@",@"23"];

Comment: I have update my original post as you mention I have change my predicate but I get the error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (CKErrorDomain error 1.)

Comment: I don't see a change in your original post. You still have a predicate for recordID

Answer (score 0):

Your recordID of 23 is stored as a CKRecordID type and not as a number thus you cannot use any numeric predicates like greater-than. You should create a new number field in your record for storing your integer IDs and query that instead.